# Running Java application as administrator needed?

Tags: java, file-io, directory, admin, directory-listing

I have a problem. This is my code:

```
File root = new File(path);
String[] entries = root.list();
LinkedList<String> out = new LinkedList<String>();
for(String entry : entries) {
 ....
}
```

In my code I'm trying to list contents of directory which is on `C:`. But this code returns me `null` on for loop start. Somewhere on the web I found that it returns `null` when file is not a directory or if I don't have administrator rights. I've tried to run Eclipse as administrator and then run my program, but I'm still getting `NullPointerException` and I don't know how to move. Does anybody know how can I edit my code or what to do to have it working? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should try calling [`File.isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) for the `root` object and checking its result before trying anything else.

It could very well be that the path in question does not actually refer to a directory or it may not even exist at all...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make yourself administrator and test it out.

Go to control panel User Accounts and Change your User Account Type to Admin.

Comment: Bingo! Now you know where your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You have to start your java program starting the **java process** as Administrator.

One way to do this is open a Console as administrator and launch your program:
e.g. Start->All programs->Accessories->Command Prompt (right-click on it, "run as administrator")

Then, from this console, you can start the java process with Admin rights:

> java yourpackage.YourProgram

Comment: You can start the java application with the remote debugging, and the connect to it with eclipse:

java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=8787,suspend=y yourapp